# Convert Date to display Month and Day .Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following line below, which currently displays like "9/29/2012"

```
<%=Convert.ToDateTime(prs["xDate"].ToString()).ToShortDateString() %>
```

I need it to display like this "Sept 29", with no year. What can I do to achieve this in .NET.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need to support multiple cultures? If so, this becomes a lot harder, as different cultures may have different approaches to displaying just "day and month".

Comment: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MMM dd` format code is the one you want for an English date format.

```
DateTime.ToString("MMM dd");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#MMM_Specifier

Comment: Thank you very much Dave, great help.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for Custom Date and Time format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx.  Construct the appropriate string, and use the overload of ToString:

```
<%=Convert.ToDateTime(prs["xDate"].ToString("format string here")).ToShortDateString() %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Convert.ToDateTime(prs["xDate"].ToString()).ToString("MMM dd")
```

Answer (score 1):

1 You can also use this format for `ToString` method

```
YourDateTime.ToString("MMMM dd");
```

Here you find all `formats of your ToString()`

Link http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

2  You can try with `Day property`

```
Console.WriteLine(YourDateTime.Day);
```

You can try with Month property

```
Console.WriteLine(YourDateTime.Month);
```

And concate